# Struggling with infinite series convergence tests

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I was working on some series calculus questions and am struggling with this particular one:

[image]

This is what I answered:

1. CG – $\int_2^\infty(\frac{1}{n\ln(n)})dn=\infty$, so it diverges according to Integral Test. Also, it isn't a $p$-series but it is close to one so can be compared with $p$-series.
2. BE – This one is a $p$-series, I know that it converges since its limit $=0$, and the graph of $y=\frac{4}{x^{\pi}}$ confirms this.
3. BD – This one is an alternating series. Also, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{1}{n\pi})=0$, the graph of $y=\frac{1}{x\pi}$ shows that it is positive and decreasing for $x\geq 1$. So, it converges conditionally according to Alternating Series Test.
4. AE – This one is a $p$-series where $p=1+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}>1$, so it converges. Since it isn't an alternating series, I stated that it absolutely converges.
5. CG – For this one, I assumed it is similar to number (1), since it is comparable to a $p$-series. And similarly to (1), it diverges according to the Integral Test.

The system shows that at least one answer is incorrect (but not which one).

Can I please get some help on this?

Comment: For 2. is AE... the rest seems to be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For case 2, the general term $\frac{4\sqrt n}{n^\pi}\
=\frac{4}{n^{\pi-\frac12}}$. Hence this one is a $p$-series as you noted. Since $\pi-\frac12>1$, the sum converges absolutely. So the answer should be "AE".

---

For case 1, the answer should be "CJ".

- For any fixed $\epsilon>0$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}}{\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^\epsilon}{\ln(n)}
  =\infty.$$ Hence although $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{1+\epsilon}}$ converges absolutely, we cannot conclude $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ converges.
- Although $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges to infinity, we cannot conclude $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ also diverges since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{n\ln(n)}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac1{\ln(n)}=0.$$

So no comparison between $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ and a $p$-series is able to determine whether $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$ converges or not.

Apparently, none of D, E, F, H and I can explain the divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{n\ln(n)}$. Hence we should choose $J$.

Using Integral Test, you have found the series diverges.